# Eclipse: Behavioral differences between "linked Resources" and "Build->Setting->include" of a head file

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am using Eclipse and do not understand what are the differences between "setting *include paths* in project setting" and "add *linked resources* in project setting" for a header file.
How do they work?

I encountered the following scenario:

I want to use a header file "*functions_api.h*", which is provided in a SDK. I have set the path to the header file in "*C/C ++ Build->Settings->Includes*", and the header file is also visible in my project.

- I can include the "*function_api.h*" and access/use its pre-defined MACROs. However when I add e.g a new *typedef* to the "*function_api.h*", the new added *typedef* is not visible in my project.
- And then I created a new file (new->file), which is linked to the "*function_api.h*". After this step, the new added *typedef* is also visible in the project.

So what I do not understand are:

1. Why the new added *typedef* is not visible before linking the "*function_api.h*" (via new->file) while other pre-defined MACROs are visible ?
2. What was changed after linking the "*function_api.h*", which make the new added *typedef* becoming visible?

Thanks
BL_

Comment: Isn't the "include" related to where eclise search for headers, while the "link" feature to what object file is linked in the link step of the compilation?

Comment: "the new added typedef is not visible in my project" What do you mean with visible? Code formatting/coloring-wise or can't you use the typedef in .c files that include the header? Regardless of Eclipse include paths, your .c files must always `#include` the header.

Comment: If `function_api.h` is not part of current project then after changing `function_api.h` you'll need to manually rebuild project index by right-clicking on project in Project Explorer -> Index -> Rebuild. Note that stale index does not prevent project from being built, it only effects syntax highlighting and autocompletion features of IDE.

Comment: @user7860670 yes, indeed it was the problem and your hints helped to solve it. Eventhough it shows syntax error, it did build successfully. And after performing Index -> Rebuild as suggested, the new typedef is visible and the syntax error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from @user7860670 has solved the problem.